# How to access particles in complextype in msxml6 using delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, msxml

I got 'the parameter is incorrect' when access to partilces in contentmodel but it is   ok to read itemtype. Can someone tell me what to do ? Thanks in advance.

```
//Book.xsd
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:bookstore-schema" targetNamespace="urn:bookstore-schema"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="book" type="booktype" />
 <xs:complexType name="booktype">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" />
     <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal" />
     <xs:element name="aaa" type="xs:string" />
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="another" type="xs:string" />
```

```
procedure AccessSchema;
var oSchemaCache : XMLSchemaCache60;
    oSchema : ISchema;
    nsTarget : string;
    kk : integer;

 procedure AccessComplexType(oComplex : iSchemaItem);
 var ISchComplex : ISchemaComplexType;
 begin
    ISchComplex := oComplex as ISchemaComplexType;

    if (iSchComplex.contentType = SCHEMACONTENTTYPE_MIXED) or
       (iSchComplex.contentType = SCHEMACONTENTTYPE_ELEMENTONLY) then
    begin
       if (iSchComplex.contentModel.ItemType = SOMITEM_CHOICE) or
          (iSchComplex.contentModel.ItemType = SOMITEM_SEQUENCE) then
       begin
         if IschComplex.contentModel.particles.length > 0 then  
         //error : the parameter is incorrect
        begin
           {handling particles }
        end;
      end;
    end;
 end; 

begin
  oSchemaCache := coXMLSchemaCache60.Create;

  nsTarget := 'urn:bookstore-schema';
  oSchemaCache.add(nsTarget,'c:\book.xsd');
  oSchema := oSchemaCache.getSchema(nsTarget);

   for kk := 0 to pred( oschema.types.length) do
   begin
      if (oschema.types.item[kk].itemType = SOMITEM_COMPLEXTYPE ) then
        AccessComplexType(oschema.types.item[kk]);
   end;
```

end;

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in your code, the problem is with the faulty Delphi 7 TLB importer.

Except for the fact that you forgot to include the `xs:schema` closing tag, your example works *just fine* if I copy-paste it into ***Delphi 2010***.

Back to ***Delphi 7***. Accessing the `.particles` property of the contentModel returns OLE code $80004001.

A quick look at the generated TLB.pas suggests Delphi 7 screwed up when importing the .TLB file. The `contentModel` is of the type `ISchemaModelGroup`, which inherits from `ISchemaItem`. Now take a look at the definition:

```
  ISchemaParticle = interface(ISchemaItem)
    ['{50EA08B5-DD1B-4664-9A50-C2F40F4BD79A}']
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_0_1; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_4_2; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_8_3; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_12_4; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_16_5; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_20_6; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_24_7; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_28_8; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_32_9; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_36_10; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_40_11; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_44_12; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_48_13; safecall;
    procedure GhostMethod_ISchemaParticle_52_14; safecall;
    function Get_minOccurs: OleVariant; safecall;
    function Get_maxOccurs: OleVariant; safecall;
    property minOccurs: OleVariant read Get_minOccurs;
    property maxOccurs: OleVariant read Get_maxOccurs;
  end;
```

See all those ghost_xxx methods? Delphi 2010 doesn't generate those, and they shouldn't be there in the first place (they cause the method offset for the get_particles call to be all wrong).

Simply comment those GhostMethod_XXX methods in the MSXML2_TLB and your example works like a charm.

However, you are stil stuck with a badly imported TLB, which might blow up in your face at any time. I'd advice you to use the Delphi 2010 imported version in stead ([MSXML2_TLB.zip](http://www.depauptits.nl//downloads/delphi/20110920/MSXML2_TLB.zip)), as it works fine with Delphi 7.